# Change style on points, d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have  this d3 polygons based on a dataset.

```
 let svg = d3.select($element[0]).append('svg')
                .attr("width", 800)
                .attr("height", 800);
            let myGroups = svg.selectAll('g').data(rooms);
            let myGroupsEnter = myGroups.enter().append("g");
            myGroupsEnter.append("polygon")
                .style("fill", "none")
                .style("stroke", "black")
                .style("strokeWidth", "10px")
                .attr("points", function (d) {
                    let q = d.footprint.coordinates.map(function (point, idx) {
                        let _d = [];
                        _d.push(scale(point[0]));
                        _d.push(scale(point[1]));
                        return _d;
                    });
                    return q.join(" ");
                });
        });
```

I want to change the `style fill` attribute on the items that meets a requirment when user selects a value from a radiobutton.

Can I somehow update this attribute? Or do I need to redraw everything?

Comment: *"on the items that meets a requirment when user selects a value from a radiobutton"*... you'll have to clarify that if you want a working answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
.style('fill', function(d) { 
     /* match item (d) with some condition */
})
```

On value change as well, you can just restyle/refill the polygons:

```
svg.selectAll('polygon').style('fill', function(d) { 
    /* match item (d) with value selected */
});
```

Comment: Yes but the condition changes with user actions. How do I update this value live?

Comment: Can you add a fiddle/codepen/plunkr of the same? It'd be clear and easier to help if there was a sample code.